# Scroll Bars Showing Up When Browser Maximized: CSS

Tags: css

The scroll bars are shown even after I maximize the browser window (I thought there should be no reason to).

There is no height issue here, and so the vertical scrollbars should not come up right?

Can anyone shed some light?

```
<style>
    html, body, div { margin: 0; border: 0 none; padding: 0; }
    html, body,form, #wrapper, #left, #right { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
    #wrapper { margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; width: 960px;  }
    #left { background: yellow; float: left; width: 360px; }
    #right { background: grey; margin-left: 360px; }
  </style>


  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
      Left
    </div>

    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `#wrapper` with a `10px margin` and `height 100%`. that will automatically give you problems. Remove the 10px margin and apply that to the inner contents of wrapper.

```css
html, body, div { margin: 0; border: 0 none; padding: 0; }
html, body,form, #wrapper, #left, #right { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
#wrapper { overflow: hidden; width: 960px;  }
#left { margin: 10px; background: yellow; float: left; width: 360px; }
#right { margin: 10px 10px 10px 360px; background: grey; }
```

Comment: Thank you both!   That fixed it.  But, I am just curious to know why this is so, as the there is not enough content to warrant for a scroll bar in the first place?

Comment: because height 100% means make the element's height 100% relative to parent. If parent is window then it will fill the screen. Then add a 10px margin - stated the way you have means add 10px to the top and the bottom. You now have a height of 100% plus 20px

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `margin:10px` from `#wrapper`.

```
#wrapper
{ 
  /*margin: 10px; */
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 960px;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you both!   That fixed it.  But, I am just curious to know why this is so, as the there is not enough content to warrant for a scroll bar in the first place?